# Autoload for controller classes in slim framework

Tags: php, composer-php, slim, autoload

I'm trying to build a site with slim and autoloading my controller classes for the routes. I'm currently setting up the base structure and testing with a single route with nothing more than a simple "Test" output.

I prevously did this stuff with defining a `spl_autoload_register` function, but as this approach isn't recommended by slim and composer I want to do it right and I'm not trying to autoload my classes.

My Project is set up as this:

[image]

The class `BlockController` inside the file with the same Name under Controller is inside a namespace defined with `namespace MyAPI\Controller;`

**app/Controller/BlockController.php**

```
namespace MyAPI\Controller;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

class BlockController
{
    public function getList(Request $request, Response $response, $args)
    {
        return $response->withStatus(200)
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            ->write("Test");
    }
}
```

I'm loading the dependencies and settings and after that all my routes (which contains currently only some small ones for testing my architecture):

**public/index.php**:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/../app/settings.php';

$app = new \Slim\App($settings);

require __DIR__ . '/../app/dependencies.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../app/routes.php';

$app->run();
```

**app/routes.php** (is very simple, will be extended with more Route-files):

```
require 'Routes/BlockRoute.php';
```

**app/Routes/BlockRoute.php**:

```
use MyAPI\Controller\BlockController;

$container["BlockController"] = function ($container) {
    return new BlockController($container);
};

$app->group('/block', function() use ($container) {
    $this->get('[/]', 'BlockController::getList');
});
```

So the first command inside BlockRoute.php is the use of the BlockController-namespace. Everything under app/ should have the Base-Namespace **MyAPI**.
As described in the [slim-documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html) I planned to do that with to autoload feature of composer, so I modified my `composer.json` and added the following:

```
{
  "require": { .. },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "MyAPI\\": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:** *updated path to app-folder after the answer from Adam Lavin*

After that I ran `composer update`. Is that the right command for those changes? Or should I use `composer install`? Couldn't find any more information what I have to do after making those additions in the autoload-section.

When I run the site now with the php webserver and navigate to this route `/block` I get the following RuntimeException:
**Callable BlockController::getList does not exist**

File: C:\Prog\src\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\CallableResolver.php

So the problem is that BlockController doesn't get included/autoloaded correctly but I don't understand why or what exactly the problem is. I tried to find some examples of working configurations with slim+composer+autoloading of classes but couldn't find something related.

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're pointing `MyApp\\` to `../src` (the same directory as composer), the autoloader is going to try and find the controller in `src/Controllers/BlockController.php`.

It should be pointing to `../src/app`, though since `composer.json` is in the `src` folder it can be simplified to `app` in the resulting `composer.json` file.

```
{
  "require": { .. },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "MyAPI\\": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

Additionally, In your example, the namespace of the `BlockController` is `MoinAPI\Controllers`, and should be `MyAPI\Controllers`.

And finally, in slim, you use a single colon instead of a double to refer to a callable route. `BlockController::getList` should be `BlockController:getList`

Comment: even if I run the site from the public folder? I tried that now and ran `composer update` - is that enough for apply those changes? It doesn't change the error message, still the same `Callable BlockController::getList does not exist` ..

Comment: Try using `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: that prints `Generating autoload files` and finishes after that. Restarting webserver after that and same effect as before..

Comment: Can you double check the namespace on the BlockController? I just noticed it isn't right in the example. `MoinAPI\Controller`

Comment: @JackO'neill See the last part of the updated answer. Though just an FYI, you still have "MoinAPI" in some of your files which you should change.

Comment: Single colon fixed the issue. It's working now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Run this **from within docker** container, or using the same php binary that composer used.

```
composer dump-autoload -o -vvv #-o fixed my problem in my case
```